# sending email based on hive query output

Tags: hive

How can I send email based on a hive query output. Say I have a table where I want to check if the number is between two other numbers of a different table. I can check that in a sql query and return sql output as 0 or 1.

Now the question is how can I send email using mailx or equivalent from the same script based on that sql output.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your script or code.

Comment: I have written the sql, which is in a hql file and I can call it from oozie workflow. But I am not sure how to call mailx based on a sql output

Comment: You don't need Oozie. Run any script that can talk to both Hive and your Email server

Answer (score 0):

> $ var=`hive -S -e "select '0' from test;"`
> $ echo $var
>
> 0
>
> $ var=`hive -S -e "select '1' from test;"`
>
> $ echo $var
>
> 1

Option : Use a shell action in oozie to run a shell script which will execute the hive command inline and capture the output as 0/1 in a variable. Use the variable in the shell to call mailx.

Comment: Hive cli is deprecated, though

Answer (score 0):

Workflow is your choice to run, you can use oozie or third-party tools or the famous cron job. You can leverage the below shell script for sending the emails based on the output of the Beeline/hive.

```
#!bin/bash
#Output variable from hive ql
Output=beeline -u ${hiveConnectionSTRING} --silent=true -e "your query that pulls the output as 0 or 1"

#Condition check and sending the email with mailx utility
if [ $Output -gt 0 ];
then
echo "output is zero"
#Email need to be added
#Username=From address(This is the name before your domain EX: Stack@domain name)
echo -e 'your email message should be here \n\n\n\nThank you,' |  mailx -r $UserName -s 'Your Subject' -c stackoverflow@gmail.com(your email cc address) -- stackoverflow@gmail.com(your email to address)0
else
echo -e 'your email message should be here \n\n\n\nThank you,' |  mailx -r $UserName -s 'Your Subject' -c stackoverflow@gmail.com(your email cc address) -- stackoverflow@gmail.com(your email to address)0 
echo "output is 1"  
fi
```